# Sharing data between C++ and C# using an in-memory SQLite database?

Tags: c#, c++, sqlite, in-memory-database

I am working in a project that features several C++ and a few C# components. I am currently working on a new C# component that needs to share data with a C++ component (there may be more components accessing this in the future). All components are running in the same process. My current idea is to use an in-memory database, but I'm not sure whether it is possible.

SQLite is popular and available for both C++ and C# projects, and it has an in-memory feature. The question is if it is possible to access the same database from both components, can I for instance use a handle to the db (pointer) created in C++ in my C# project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that would be possible. Of course, you'd need to share some data structures and handles (as you say). That way SQLite cannot detect any difference between managed code and native code. Therefore there can be no difference in behavior.

Maybe it is easier if you just use PInvoke or C++/CLI to exchange data structures. Spinning up a whole SQL database just for passing around data in-process seems wasteful.

Comment: The idea of using a database came from the future (likely) possibility of more components using (creating, modifying) the same data. With a database I wouldn't have to write code to handle this. Putting it in-memory seemed like a good idea since the data is obsolete once the application closes, and the application wouldn't need to bother with the file system. As for performance there is network communication in the system that will always be the bottleneck, the db would be minor in comparison. Do you still feel this is a wasteful approach?

Comment: It is entirely reasonable according to the points you made. The only question left would be: What approach is a little work as possible? I still doubt that an in-memory database is less work to program than a few PInvoke calls with well-known data structures. But if the data lends itself well to this kind of storage it is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. The sqlite database is in memory but it resides as a file on disk. When you close the database connection it is flushed on to the file on disk. So you can basically open the db connection in one component write and close the connection so that other components can read/write into db. Its just similar to how you operate of files except that it is managed in memory rather then on disk so bit faster than files. But if your intention is IPC between c++ and c# there are other better ways.

Comment: SQLite in-memory databases (`:memory:`) do not have a file.